# Is it possible to control elements in WSDL minOccurs maxOccurs?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, behavior, custom-attributes

is it possible writing WCF, that will expose my properties with controllable maxOccurs?

`<xs:element name="param" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" />`

What I have only found, it's control over complex types.

Thanx in advance.